# What should you put as an HTTP Referrer for the Javascript Google Places API with an Ionic mobile app?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would like my Javascript Google Places and Map API browser key to be secure. I am getting a warning about adding a referrer.

What should I put as a referrer if it is an Ionic mobile app and not a website? How can I secure this?

Warning message: [image]

Comment: I believe that Ionic uses Cordova to run an HTTP server to serve files from the device into the webview. You might have to dig into the documentation a bit but it's probably `localhost` on some port or an internal IP address. Unfortunately that doesn't make it much more secure but there's not much you can do about that if you're making a Cordova web app because the "origin" is the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

A Ionic app is a hybrid app so it uses a headless browser running full screen.
Read here: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/

Regarding your question here you can use [CordovaHTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) as a plugin to create custom headers which will match Google HTTP Referers:

```
cordovaHTTP.setHeader("Header", "Value");
```

But for testing you can leave it blank, it is required before putting into production.

Comment: In that case he might as well just use the XMLHttpRequest API. But I thought it was impossible to modify the Origin or Referer header programmatically, which is what he would need to do in order for Google to accept the request? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Comment: Ah so seems like the advantage of cordovaHTTP is that it is capable of setting forbidden headers, unlike the JavaScript API.

Comment: @Always hungry - Can you please explain what you mean by "create custom headers which will match Google HTTP Referers". Can you please give an example. Thanks.